# How do I install Ubuntu without erasing Windows 10

Tags: system-installation

I made a bootable USB with Ubuntu and I want to try a bit of Linux. I have an SSD in my laptop which shows only one partition. Now, I want to be able to choose which OS to run when my machine boots up and I don't know if I should just install Ubuntu when I reset my laptop and will that way everything I have on windows still be there or I need to make another partition. So I just want to be able to run both OS's without any of my files being erased. Thanks.

Comment: If you run the Ubuntu installer from Live media, the installer will ask you what to do with partitiion.

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I install Ubuntu alongside a pre-installed Windows with UEFI?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-alongside-a-pre-installed-windows-with-uefi).  GRUB is installed with Ubuntu and when dual-booting, it will allow you to select the OS at boot.

Answer (score 0):

Creating dual boot is relatively easy regardless of what os came first on the machine. 
In your case, you want to install ubuntu when Windows already exists, and by using the live method. It is a simple matter of choosing 1-2 options at the installation menu.

Here is a good guide with screen captures of the necessary steps that might be useful: [How to dual-boot Linux and Windows](https://opensource.com/article/18/5/dual-boot-linux)